implementing RxDb with my mern application
I an a total noob and I'm tying to use Rxdb with my mern application for offline experience
I'm trying to use Rxdb to save some data locally present in mongodb for offline use. in a normal mern application we have a node endpoint which returns some data and we access this endpoint in react using axios.
but when i try to use RxDb it looks like a complete nightmare to me. like creating a local rxDb, sync with my remote mongodb, how does it sync, how to access these data to use in my UI, etc.. And the RxDb documentation is hard for me to understand.
can some one guide me or share me any github repos which implements rxdb, videos or any other documentation

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
